# Как перетянуть мои дочерные UI обьекты на передний план?

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Как переместить обьекты Cell на передний план? Не могу использовать Drag & Drop на этих обьектах.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно зайти в Layers создать слой Menu и поставить на место выше чем остальные слои.
Потом нужно применить этот слой на твой канвас.

Comment: Пробывал, не помогает.

Comment: не может не помогать. :) Это помогает, даже, с частицами, хотя там эту процедуру сделать значительно сложнее. Ты что-то делаешь не так.

Comment: Да вроде все так, но положение UI елементов не меняется.

Comment: Канвас должен быть с настройкой screen overlay или как-то так. Если же канвас неправильно настроен, то вполне возможно что на сцене будут элементы меню находится ЗА какими-то обьектами.

Comment: Канвас именно такой у меня и присутствует.